# Overwriting common XML styles

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a common component with XML styles that is shared between two apps.  I want to be able to change the Font of that style in both apps but don't want to rebuild the component.  Is it possible to overwrite the components style in the app layer?

My common style

```xml
<style name="BoldText">
     <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/opensans_bold</item>
</style>
```

How can I overwrite this within my application layer without having to extend the style?

**Update**

Need to explain this better.  I have a common component that references a common layout file in a module that my two apps use.  Using the common component in my application layer I do not want to provide it with a new Layout file, but I do want the references to "BoldText" to be updated with the new font, provided by the Application layer.

**Folder Structure**

```
-common
--src
---CheckboxWithDetails.kt
--res
---layouts
----checkbox_with_details.xml
-app
--src
---SomePageUsingCheckboxWithDetails.kt
-OtherApp
--src
---OtherPageUsingCheckboxWithDetails.kt
```

Within `SomePage` I need the font for the checkbox with details to be a different font and then in `OtherPage` I need the font to be another different font.

I just want to avoid making two different layouts and wondering if this is currently possible.

Comment: Could you show your 'current' application layer?

Comment: hey @ivan I updated with my folder structure to better highlight what I am going for here.

Comment: Yes it is possible to change the font of an element programatically.
If you are doing this with a custom elements you need to change it so before it returns the view you set the new font with an argument.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! You can achieve this in your application layer.

```
<style name="newBoldText" parent="BoldText">
     <item name="android:fontFamily">NEW_FONT</item>
</style>
```

Now you should use

`style="@style/newBoldText"`

in your application layer instead of

`style="@style/BoldText"`

Comment: Hey Thank you Derek.  I updated my question a bit as the problem is I don't have access to the Layout to update the style.  I want to update the layout from the application layer.

Answer (score 0):

So I did figure this out.  You can define attributes as 'reference' and then it is as simple as just passing the reference to the font attribute you want from your application layer.

This does not fix the original problem of overwriting a style from a common component, however it is a solution in case you are looking to have custom common components for multiple apps.

Attributes are defined as this:

```
<declare-styelable name="CustomComponent">
     <attr name="messageFont" format="reference" />
</declare-styleable>
```

With this within the App layer.

```
<CustomComponent
   app:messageFont=@font/opensans_regular />
```